# What does 2 in J2SE and J2EE represent?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was reading about the history and different versions of Java, and learned about `J2EE` and `J2SE`. But i got confused about why the number `2` is used in between them. My questions are:

1) If `2` stands for second edition, then were there some other first edition for Java?

2)If yes how different was it from the current second edition?

Note: I read that `J2EE` and `J2SE` is renamed to `Java-SE` and `Java-EE` respectively. But the question "why did they used the number 2 earlier?" remains there.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition#Nomenclature,_standards_and_specifications): *The "2" was originally intended to emphasize the major changes introduced in version **1.2**, but was removed in version 1.6.*

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, since a search for `J2SE` immediately lead to the Wikipedia article, which explains the "2".

Comment: *"If `2` stands for second edition, then were there some other first edition for Java?"* There was Java 1.0 and 1.1. If you read the [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) page on Wikipedia you'll see that.